# Python Dictionary how to substitute the list of values to make dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

i have the following dictionary:

```
xx = {'tech': [{'name': 'Bootstrap', 'version': None}, {'name': 'jQuery', 'version': '3.3.1'}, {'name': 'Bootstrap', 'version': '3.3.7'}], 'headers': [{'value': 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2', 'name': 'Server'}]}
```

And I would like to convert the above dictionary to the following format. where `name` should act as `KEY` and `version` or `value` should act as `Value` of the dictionary.

```
xx = {'http://mychoicedomain.com': {'Bootstrap':'3.3.7','jQuery':'3.3.1','Server':'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2'}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the values first then combining them into values does the job.

```
x1 = {d['name']:d['version'] for d in xx['tech']}
x2  = {d['name']:d['value'] for d in xx['headers']}
xx = {}
xx['http://mychoicedomain.com'] = dict(**x1,**x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xx = {'http://mychoicedomain.com':{d['name']:d['version'] for d in xx['tech']}}
```

Comment: If the list of dictionaries has multiple dictionaries with the same `name`, this code will keep only the last one.

Comment: You missed `headers`.